# If statement to cycle through individual elements in array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, rgb

In my code, I am trying to import a grayscale image (2D array) and then solve for the optical density (OD) based off an empirical formula I came up with.  The optical density has a relationship with the grayscale value where `OD = 0.51*((f-22.08)/(176.09-f))**(1./-1.519)` where f is the grayscale value of each element in the array.  Then, I converted it into an RGB image.

My problem is I am trying to run each individual element of the image array into an if statement.  It does not enter the statement though.  What I want to do is increase the intensity of each individual element or pixel value in R, G, and B based on what condition is met with the optical density.  Say if it has an OD value that falls between b and c, it adds [128,0,0] to each element that satisfies that criteria.

```
t = Image.open("IMG_1.jpg").convert('L') #grayscale image
f = array(t) #Convert test image into an array

OD = 0.51*((f-22.08)/(176.09-f))**(1./-1.519) #Empirical Rodbard formula
OD[np.isnan(OD)] = 0

def to_rgb5(im):
    OD.resize((OD.shape[0], OD.shape[1], 1))
    return np.repeat(OD.astype(np.uint8), 3, 2)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')

rgba_img = cmap(OD)
rgb_img = np.delete(rgba_img, 3, 2)

a = 0.08
b = 0.11
c = 0.15

if np.all(OD < a):
    background_noise = rgb_img
    if np.all(OD < b):
        small = rgb_img + [128, 0, 0]
    elif np.all(OD >= c):
        large = rgb_img + [0, 0, 128]


Red = f + small
Green = f
Blue = f + large
```

Comment: Does your code throw errors? Tabulation looks wrong and `:` missing

Comment: Sorry, I lost that coping it over.  The only that occurs is that it says "NameError: name 'small' is not defined"

Comment: Doubt it. `else np.all(OD >= C)` can't work.

Comment: That hasn't come up since it is not entering the loops for some reason.  I check my values for OD and they range from 0 to 0.4 so at least some values should show up.

Comment: Your `if` statement either sets `small` or `large`, it never sets both. So when you try to use those variables after that, you get an error for the one that's not set.

Comment: So I would need to write another `if` instead of `else`?

Comment: You should assign default values to `small` and `large` before the `if`.

Comment: You say it is not entering the loops... what loops? Can't see any.

Comment: `else` should be `elseif` since you have a condition after it.

Comment: What image module are you using?

Comment: I am using PIL and numpy for arrays

Comment: @Barmar: `elif`, not `elseif`

Comment: @tobias_k I meant to say it is not entering the if statements.

Comment: OD should be grayscale, not rgb.  I missed another part of the code.  And I will add something about OD when I edit it.

Comment: Think you need to use `np.where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it work using the np.where suggested by @Stuart

```
t = Image.open("IMG_1.jpg").convert('L') #grayscale image
f = array(t) #Convert test image into an array

OD = 0.51*((f-22.08)/(176.09-f))**(1./-1.519) #Empirical Rodbard formula
OD[np.isnan(OD)] = 0

thB = 0.02
ththin = 0.11
ththick = 0.15

GSb = 162
GSthin = 150
GSthick = 145

if np.where(OD < ththin):
    thresholded = threshold(f, GSthin, GSb)
def to_rgb1(thresholded):
    thresholded.resize((thresholded.shape[0], thresholded.shape[1], 1))
    return np.repeat(thresholded.astype(np.uint8), 3, 2)       
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
rgba_img1 = cmap(thresholded)
rgb_img1 = np.delete(rgba_img1, 3, 2)
view = rgb_img1[:, :, 2]
view[view < 0.1] += 128 
thin = rgb_img1

if np.where(OD > ththick):
    thresholded2 = threshold(f, threshmax = GSthick)
def to_rgb2(thresholded2):
    thresholded2.resize((thresholded2.shape[0], thresholded2.shape[1], 1))
    return np.repeat(thresholded2.astype(np.uint8), 3, 2)       
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
rgba_img2 = cmap(thresholded2)
rgb_img2 = np.delete(rgba_img2, 3, 2)
view2 = rgb_img2[:, :, 0]
view2[view2 > 0] += 128  
thick = rgb_img2
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I don't think it's the right usage of `where`. I think you need something like `small = np.where(OD < b, rgb_img + [128, 0, 0], rgb_img)`

Comment: I get this error when I do it that way `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1080,1920) (2,)`

Comment: Yes, you need to check that the arrays being added together are the same shape. That was just an example of how `np.where` is supposed to work.